# Attempting to Export Creative Exchange through script web api

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions, creative-exchange

I'm attempting to follow the documentation for SXA in a [CI/CD process](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/trigger-creative-exchange-from-your-ci-server.html#UUID-ba297792-7315-ceeb-348e-7e5c72561914_id__The_endpoints).

**Configuration Details:**

- Sitecore 9.1 (Standalone Config - My Local Dev)
- SXA 1.8 initial release
- PowerShell 5
- Running on Windows Server 2016 Standard Edition

Per the documentation, I created my own Web API endpoints in my Project folder of the PowerShell Scripts.  I copied the scripts for import and export into my respective copies of the script items.

When I called the web API endpoint using the following path:
`/-/script/v2/master/site-export-script`

I received the following response:

```
> Exception calling "Run" with "2" argument(s): "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex"
At line:135 char:9
+         [Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline]::Run("ceExport.export", $ex ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

This is the Cmdlet from the `Get-CreativeExchangeExportResponse`

**Function Path:**

`/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/SXA - Creative Exchange/Functions/CI/Get-CreativeExchangeExportResponse`

```
[Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline]::Run("ceExport.export", $exportArgs);
```

I'm adding this in hopes someone can help speed my research up.  Thanks in advance.

#### Update: 6/24/2019

This is the script file that is run and give the exception below:

```bsh
Import-Function Get-CreativeExchangeExportResponse

$item = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Home"

$exportArgs = Get-CreativeExchangeExportResponse -CurrentItem $item -DeviceId "{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}"

$responseObject = @{
    "Messages" = $exportArgs.Messages;
    "Result"   = $exportArgs.CreativeExchangeExportStorage.GetResult()
}
Set-HostProperty -HostWidth 9999
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeObject($responseObject)
```

Running this code in the PowerShell ISE for Sitecore still produces the following stack trace:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At line:115 char:39
+ ... ntextData = New-Object -TypeName "Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchang ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:2 char:5
+     $websitePath = [System.Web.HttpContext]::Current.Server.MapPath(" ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Set-Content : Cannot find path 'master:\CE_auth_c4464daa-f673-4505-81d7-62f3940748fc-2019-06-24T13.55.16.8315406-05.00.aspx' because it does not exist.
At line:16 char:5
+     Set-Content -Value $loginString -Path $filePath
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (master:\CE_auth...5406-05.00.aspx:String) [Set-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand

Send-AuthenticationRequest : An Error occured during authentication. Please clean all authentication data
At line:116 char:23
+ ...        $exportArgs = Send-AuthenticationRequest $exportArgs $UserName
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Send-AuthenticationRequest

System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:42 char:9
+         $websitePath = [System.Web.HttpContext]::Current.Server.MapPa ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "GetCookies" with "1" argument(s): "This operation is not supported for a relative URI."
At line:45 char:5
+     $s.Cookies.GetCookies($Uri) | % {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

Exception calling "Run" with "2" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At line:135 char:9
+         [Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline]::Run("ceExport.export", $ex ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException

{"Result":{"Result":" /App_Data/packages/CreativeExchange\\FileStorage\\Site","Type":2},"Messages":[]}
```

Comment: Can you provide the script and demonstrate that it works from within the ISE?

Comment: @MichaelWest I have added the details above.

Comment: @DerekPort were you able to find the solutions of this issue?
I am facing with same on Sitecore 9.3...

Comment: @Anton I got the import working in 9.3 using the included web-api endpoint as an example. I made my own api-endpoint that is called during our release process.  In the case above for 9.1, I did get a sitecore support modified script, but didn't have time to implement that for the specific project I was working on at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue on a different version of Sitecore and SXA. And here is the solution that works for me.

`Get-CreativeExchangeExportResponse` executes `ceExport.export` pipeline.

`ceExport.export` pipeline requires initialization of `ExportArgs`

ExportArgs has many properties, but we are interested in `HttpContextData`

```
public class ExportArgs : PipelineArgs, IMessages
{
    ...
    public HttpContextData HttpContextData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    ...
}
```

`HttpContextData` parameterless constructor depends on `HttpContext.Current`

```
public class HttpContextData
{
    public HttpContextData()
        : this(HttpContext.Current)
    {
    }
}
```

It means that we need to execute Sitecore Powershell script with `HttpContext`, otherwise it will throw an exception.

It means that we if you are using Sitecover Powershell ISE: by default, the script executes as a background job. You can try to click on dropdown under Execute button and select "Execute in http request context"

[image]

And if we execute Sitecore Powershell as [a remote script](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/remoting) then we should not use `-AsJob` parameter.