# SXA Creative Exchange Import triggered via SPE not working

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions, creative-exchange

I was trying to set up a `CI/CD` according to the documentation, where I planned to trigger a Creative Exchange Import via Sitecore Powershell Extensions Web Api.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/trigger-creative-exchange-from-your-ci-server.html

I am currently running `Sitecore 9.3` on `Azure PaaS` and `Sitecore Powershell Extensions 6.0`

I tracked the error down to a script, that came with SXA: `/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/SXA - Creative Exchange/Functions/CI/Get-CreativeExchangeImportResponse`

I changed the content, so I can run only the script in itself and added a function call at the bottom. Apart from that, I made no changes.

```
function Get-CreativeExchangeImportResponse {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Item]$CurrentItem,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Storage.CreativeExchangeStorageDefinition]$StorageDefinition,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false )]
        [int]$FileSizeLimit = 0,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [Sitecore.Data.ID]$DeviceId = "{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}"     
    )

    begin {
        Write-Verbose "Cmdlet Get-CreativeExchangeImportResponse - Begin"
        # switch off Write-Progress used in Invoke-WebRequest
        $progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'
        Import-Function Get-StorageDefinition
    }

    process {
        Write-Verbose "Cmdlet Get-CreativeExchangeImportResponse - Process"

        # assign default parameters
        if ($StorageDefinition -eq $null) {
            $StorageDefinition = Get-StorageDefinition $CurrentItem "Folder on server"
        }

        if ($MarkupMode -eq $null) {
            $MarkupMode = [Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Enums.MarkupMode]::AgencyDrop
        }
        
        if ($ExportScope -eq $null) {
            $ExportScope = [Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Enums.ExportScope]::Site
        }
        
        if ($BucketExportMode -eq $null) {
            $BucketExportMode = [Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Enums.BucketExportMode]::OneOfTemplate
        }        

        $importArgs = New-Object -TypeName "Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Pipelines.Import.Import.ImportArgs"
        $importArgs.HttpContext = [System.Web.HttpContext]::Current

        $importContext = New-Object -TypeName "Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Models.Import.ImportContext"
        $importContext.StorageServiceDefinition = $StorageDefinition
        $importContext.DeviceId = $DeviceId
        $importContext.Database = $CurrentItem.Database
        $importContext.ImportOptions = New-Object -TypeName "Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Models.Import.ImportOptions"
        $importArgs.ImportContext = $importContext


        [Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline]::Run("ceImport.import", $importArgs);
        $importArgs
    }

    end {
        Write-Verbose "Cmdlet Get-CreativeExchangeImportResponse - End"
    }
}

Get-CreativeExchangeImportResponse -CurrentItem (Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Home")
```

As I run this script, I get the following error message

```
Exception calling "Run" with "2" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At line:52 char:9
+         [Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline]::Run("ceImport.import", $im ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException



ImportContext           : Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Models.Import.ImportContext
HttpContext             :
CreativeExchangeStorage : Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Storage.Import.FileImportStorage
Messages                : {}
ThemeAssets             : {}
CustomData              : {}
Aborted                 : False
Message                 :
ProcessorItem           :
Suspended               : False
```

What I read from this, is that `$importArgs` is not quite what the pipeline expects. I debugged through the script and `$importArgs` is null or so I think and I'm not sure, what exactly the args should contain for the pipeline to run.

Has anyone experienced this error before?
I'd be glad for some info or maybe a hint where to look. I guess my next step would be to decompile the pipeline itself and check what could cause this issue there.

Thanks for any hints,
Simon

Comment: Can you provide an example of the actual script you are running? From the documentation link you provided, there is more to it than just the function `Get-CreativeExchangeImportResponse`.

Comment: Hi Michael,
I tried to run the script as described in the doc:
```/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/SXA - Creative Exchange/Web API/ce-import```
and in there the script from my question is called. But in the ```ce-import``` is not much additional logic other than getting the item from the path and then calling the Get-```CreativeExchangeImportResponse``` function with the current item set

Comment: I cannot 100% confirm yet, but my guess for now, that it has something to do with the context.
I retried and checked all parameters again and now the script at least works, when triggered via Web Api (also as described in the doc)
However I still get the same error, when running the script in Powershell ISE

Comment: Conceptually, we use Creative Exchange Live as a design time process and not at build time.  The front-end devs have it so that the theme updates get pushed into the Sitecore Media library via gulp watchers, and then Unicorn manages the data from there.  This is a much simpler model than trying to import content into Sitecore mid-CI/CD build I would think.  Perhaps you are trying to solve a problem you shouldn't even have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got [a very similar issue](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19402/attempting-to-export-creative-exchange-through-script-web-api/28336), but with Sitecore SXA Creative Exchange content export. It looks like the reason is the same here.

`Get-CreativeExchangeImportResponse` executes `ceImport.import` pipeline.

`ceImport.import` pipeline requires initialization of `ImportArgs`

`ImportArgs` need to have `HttpContext` to be initilized.

It means that we need to execute Sitecore Powershell script with `HttpContext`, otherwise it will throw an exception.

It means that we if you are using Sitecover Powershell ISE: by default, the script executes as a background job. You can try to click on dropdown under Execute button and select "Execute in http request context"

[image]

And if we execute Sitecore Powershell as [a remote script](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/remoting) then we should not use `-AsJob` parameter.